# Problem Joining Windows Server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, active-directory

i was trying to connect my ubuntu 18.04 to my company windows server by this tutorial

https://bitsofwater.com/2018/05/08/join-ubuntu-18-04-to-active-directory/

all went great until i tried to join the domain like this:

```
realm join --verbose --user=administrator --computer-ou=OU=Linux,DC=Tager,DC=com tager.com
```

but that produced this error:

```
! The organizational unit does not exist: OU=Linux,DC=Tager,DC=com
adcli: joining domain TAGER.COM failed: The organizational unit does not exist: OU=Linux,DC=Tager,DC=com
```

! Failed to join the domain
    realm: Couldn't join realm: Failed to join the domain

I don't know what what to do now

Comment: I guess it's enough to run the same command without the --computer-ou argument. Otherwize, check you created the folder Linux in Root of your AD.